# Proof and correctness of the projected gradient descent

Tags: optimization, constraints, gradient-descent

I would like to estimate a matrix $S$ by solving this optimization problem \begin{align}
&\min\limits_{s} f(S) \\
&\text{subject to }\sum_{i,j\neq\{1,1\}}s_{i,j}=1 \\
&\text{subject to }s_{1,1}=-0.5,\end{align}
where I would like to have all the entries $s_{i,j}$ except $s_{1,1}$ of my solution matrix S sum up to 1 and $s_{1,1}=-0.5$.

So the way how I solved the problem is by the following iterative equations at every iteration $k+1$:
\begin{align}
&s_{i,j}^{(k+1)}= s_{i,j}^{k} - \eta\nabla f\big(s_{i,j}^{(k)}\big)\\
&s^{(k+1)}_{i,j\neq{\{1,1\}}} = \frac{s^{(k+1)}_{i,j\neq{\{1,1\}}}}{\sum_{i,j\neq\{1,1\}}s^{(k+1)}_{i,j}} \\
&s^{(k+1)}_{1,1}=-0.5\end{align}

The main idea is to solve using the gradient decent then projecting the updated entries back into the feasible set by reinforcing the constraints at each iteration $k+1$.

My final solution is what I need but I would like to know if and when what I am doing is correct and is there a proof for that. I know that this may depend on the function $f$ so that would be great to explain under which conditions the way how I am solving my problem is correct.

Comment: Are you looking for local or global optimality? What is $f$? How is $\eta$ selected? Would you like to know if this procedure works all the time, or just for your example?

Comment: @LinAlg thank you so much you brought a very important point that I should clarify in my question. Yes I would like to know when and why my procedure works with a proof that would be awesome.

Comment: A quick search for "projected gradient descent" shows that you have a valid algorithm, but that convergence to a global optimum depends on convexity of $f$ and on the choice for $\eta$; e.g. https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ggordon/10725-F12/slides/08-general-gd.pdf

Comment: @LinAlg: Thanks a lot! The projected gradient descent that's exactly what I was looking for.